# Why is it impossible (if it actually is) to speculate about physical impossibilities?

Tags: soft-question

I've come across situations where a non-physicist person ask a physicist a question like "what would happen if a human travelled faster than the speed of light?" and the physicist would answer "that's impossible", and refused to give any more detailed answer. I'm not under the assumption that physicists are grumpy and just don't want to think about that sort of stuff, I think there is a point behind the idea that there is no point in speculation about impossibilities. But what is really the case?

Is it possible, in any meaningful way, to speculate about physical impossibilities?

Comment: you see, physicists refuse to answer that kind of questions precisely because they have thought "*about that sort of stuff*", more than anyone else

Comment: Reaching a conclusion that something is impossible (in the context of "what is currently known about physics") is *not* speculation. Anything beyond that is meaningless, since anybody can make up whatever they like. Some philosophers might find it interesting to discuss whether or not questions like "what color would elephants' eggs be, if elephants laid eggs" have any meaning, but physicists usually have other things to do.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking these types of questions. Most discoveries come after decades of that same sort of thought process. Sometimes it's not that they weren't asking the questions, sometimes they could've been thinking about it all wrong to begin with and we're not asking the right questions. Then somebody discovers one thing new and everyone looks at the whole thing differently from then on. So questions like you're asking are never too stupid to ask. At least I hope not.

Comment: Your hypotheticals ask 'suppose physics is wrong, what does physics say happens?' well the answer is really 'no one knows because it's undefined behavior' and that is why, I'd argue, that physicists don't like these types of questions.

Comment: No, it is not impossible, many physicist do this. Actually there are numerous ways to step over this "speed limit" (for example, phase speed or Alcubierre-drives), and yes they are mainstream things.

Comment: -1. I think this is a question about philosophy, not physics.

Comment: A small point,  I know but you ask : **Is it possible, in any meaningful way, to speculate about physical impossibilities?**  No, I don't think it is. But that's not to close the door forever on current "impossible" questions that may turn out to be possible later. Science is full of such examples.

Answer (score 3):

Without a consistent model any discussion about hypothetical situations is meaningless. It's not per se wrong to discuss the possibility of faster than light travel, but you must do that within a mathematically consistent framework. This also applies to some of the experimental limits on violations of certain physical laws law,  take e.g. the experimental limit on the charge of the photon. As [Lev Okun explains here](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0505250) this is meaningless because you can't construct a well defined theory where the photon has a charge. The mass of the photon is also an interesting case, as [pointed out in this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0306245), the limits on the photon mass as deduced from experiments depend on the theoretical model that describes massive photons.

Comment: Up vote for your first sentence. A hypothetical model is what you need to question. Ignoring the hypotheticals just because you were absolutely sure may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to physical impossibilities, I do think that there is a distinction between

1. Outcomes that are mathematically realizable based on a currently accepted mathematical framework but not physically possible.
2. Outcomes that do not mathematically or physically realizable.

I think that exotic matter such as tachyons or negative mass is a good example of category one.  The scientific community widely agrees that these types of particles do not exist.  That being said, in the case of tachyons we can predict that their causality would be reversed.  That's a consequence of using the time dilation equation for superluminal velocities.

I think that asking questions such as "What are some expected properties of superluminal particles?" can be a valuable exercise.  It's a good pedagogical tool that reinforces our current understanding of the maximum speed at which information can be transmitted.  However, it also shows that physics relies on predictions.  So, we can say confidently that superluminal particles are likely impossible because the predictions of what a superluminal particle *would* look like remain unfilled.  As a result we have both experimental and theoretical considerations when talking about physical impossibilities.

On the other hand, we've seen some pretty hair-brained pet theories floated on this site (and elsewhere) that falls squarely into the second category.  When people try to talk about The Electric Universe, or cold fusion, there is not even a theoretical framework with which we can engage those ideas.  It is meaningless to even speculate about those situations, because there's like no point of contact with our physical reality at all, which we could use as a departure point.